# How can I remove thick dust on the top of a wardrobe?

Tags: dust

I am talking about dust that have been accumulated for years. The options that I've considered are:

1. a vacuum cleaner. However it's container is too small and it's very hard to use it on a ladder.
2. Using wet towels. It looks like a lot of work that will release dust to the air.
3. Applications using static electricity. I've no experience with this.

What would you suggest as the best practice?

Comment: Cleaning is ontopic : "For questions relating to the removal of dirt, debris and other unwanted foreign material from various surfaces and porous materials, including methods, tools and supplies, and expected results."

Answer (score 1):

1. Cover entire top of wardrobe with king sized bed sheet.  Lay it down gently across the top, right on the dust.  Don't stir it up.
2. Scoot edges in along the top of wardrobe, pushing dust in front of them.  Dust pushed into the air will remain trapped under the sheet.
3. When you have pushed edges in to center, dust will be inside sheet.  Gather edges in the middle of the wardrobe and take sheet (now bag) outside to shake dust out.
4. Bring sheet back in and use it to wipe off residual dust.  Take back outside to shake.
5. Bring sheet back in and use furniture polish and sheet to clean wardrobe top.

would it be too much to ask that you post a picture of the dust?  Prurient interest, perhaps, but I want to see dust that thick.

Comment: It looks exactly how you'd think it looks: a quarter inch of brownish grey fuzz. idk why people are vtc this. have they never moved furniture before?

Comment: I liked this answer (still I wonder - nobody recommends the static electricity option?). However It's too close to the ceiling to get a clear and well lit picture..

Answer (score 0):

- a vacuum cleaner with a wand
- wet rag, after you use a floor scooper or straight piece of cardboard to **first shovel up as much as possible** (wet rag after you vacuum - and shovel up before vacuuming, to save on the filter - *if* you're ok with getting a poof of dust in your face). No vacuum? : shovel and wet rag.
- static electricity: take a balloon and rub it on your head, then...

Comment: If you just go at it with a wet rag, you'll turn that dust into paint, on what's probably an unsealed wood surface. yuck.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a idea a whack,

Big box stores sell plasticpaint scrapers. Plastic used thoughtfully will not destroy a finished surface if you have one.

Tape a garbage bag to an opposing side of the wardrobe so that its opening (mouth) is readily accessible and dirt will fall into it.

Scrape towards the bag from the outer edges working in.

Similar to shoveling a driveway.

Vacuum the remainder with a brush attachment.

Dust regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the garbage bag taped to one side of the wardrobe then scrape the dust into the bag and then wipe clean with a wet rag. After that help it from collecting by using a swiffer want with folding arm extension and keep it dusted off.